# Finding roots of equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have the next equation:

[image]

I wrote it in mathematica and I obtained

```
f[h_] = 8 - 5 (-(2 - h) Sqrt[4 h - h^2] + 4 Sec[(2 - h)/2])
```

Now I have to solve it, finding the `h`.
I know that `h` is between `0<=h<=4` by the Sqrt equation but I don't know how to find the real root. I tried with NSolve or FindRoot but it didn't work.

Comment: you know the notation `cos^-1` usually denotes inverse cosine not 1/cos..(sec)

Comment: indeed changing `Sec` to `ArcCos` you should get a solution around `h=.74`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Corrected `eqn` for missing `L`

```
eqn = V == (r^2 ArcCos[(r - h)/r] - (r - h) Sqrt[2 r h - h^2])L;

const = {r -> 2, L -> 5, V -> 8};
```

The exact solution for `h` is a [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) object

```
sol = Solve[eqn /. const, h, Reals][[1]]

{h -> Root[{-(8/5) + 4 ArcCos[(2 - #1)/2] - 
      2 Sqrt[-(-4 + #1) #1] + #1 Sqrt[-(-4 + #1) #1] &, 
    0.74001521805594051394}]}
```

The numeric approximation is

```
sol // N

(* {h -> 0.740015} *)
```

Verifying that the solution satisfies the equation

```
eqn /. const /. sol // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

or

```
eqn /. const /. N[sol]

(* True *)

Plot[Evaluate[eqn /. const], {h, 0, 4},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{h /. sol, 0}]}]
```

[image]